# Deleted pictures still showing up when using the Photo app in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, photos

I have a folder on my computer with pictures that I view using the Photos application, and delete using the same application if I don't want them.
But even after being deleted, those still show up on the viewer when I go through the pictures.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: cloud/ms live account online storage not synced?

Comment: thanks, I figured out it had to do with the microsoft account, so I changed some of the settings, and now it seems to work.                                           thank you.

Comment: you can post your own answer and accept it if you remember the steps you took.

Answer (score 2):

- Open the "photos" application
- Go to "settings"
- I disabled most of the options, but the one that made the change i
  needed is probably the "linked duplicates" one.

Answer (score 0):

Open file explorer.. Find the deleted photos, use "Search" if you have to because they'll mostly remain invisible from view. Select the stubborn, undeletable img files, click on the "Home" tab.. then go over to "Properties" ..in the pull down menu choose "Remove Properties"..
And Voila! gone from PC, gone from your Windows Photo viewer

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
SOLUTION: Turn Off Indexing for your Drive. My Computer > right-click on your local drive (C, D, etc) > Properties > On the General tab, UNCHECK “Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties”  > Select "Apply these settings to all files and subfolder".

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the "Pohotos" app and in the top right corner click on the three dots and hit refresh. Worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked. Running this batch file did the job. Create a clear.bat file and add this to it. Note you have to kill explorer and launch it again.

```
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*

del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*

del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\*

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on app tile, go to app settings and reset the app. Has worked for me